# Batch Linear Unmixing

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, image-processing, mixing

Linear unmixing means to solve a set of linear equations to get the proportions of basic elements in the final composit. It is a linear mixture. If we have $f$ features and $m$ basic elements: 
\begin{equation} Y_{f\times 1} = M_{f\times m}F_{m\times 1}+\epsilon_{f\times 1} \end{equation}

where $Y$ is the estimated linear mixture vector, $M$ is the  matrix of basic elements, and $\epsilon$ is the error.

This is like a linear regression or ordinary least squares and has closed form solutions. The problem is the above is just for one pixel, my question is can we do linear unmixing for a list of pixels in one shot? Instead of rerunning the above for each?

For example if we want to do above for $n$ data points one might model it like:

\begin{equation} Y_{f\times n } = M_{f\times m}F_{m\times n}+\epsilon_{f\times n} \end{equation}

I am not sure how to solve above equation in closed form (in one shot).

Comment: Are you sure that the least squares solution changes? Won't the normal equations just involve a matrix-matrix product rather than a matrix-vector product?

Comment: That's why I asked, not sure how it might work like that..